# Pagination with window function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to paginate the over profiles assuming that each profile has one email address. I want to get user's latest email address (current one). For some reason the latest email is not the only one being returned in the first query whereas the second one is correct.

```
select distinct ON (email) email, count(*) over()
from "profile" 
where "email" = 'example@test.com' 
order by "email" desc, "created_date" desc limit 1
```

returns:

```
email             | count
------------------+------
example@test.com  |    18
```

```
select distinct ON (email) email
from "profile" 
where "email" = 'example@test.com' 
order by "email" desc, "created_date" desc limit 10
```

returns:

```
email
----------------
example@test.com
```

Comment: Window functions are executed *before* the `LIMIT` clause, so you get the number of *all* profiles with that `email`, not only the latest one. But what else would you like to count here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid code duplication when you want to get the paged list, and the count of whole list regardless of page's size, you can use [CTE](http://www.anicehumble.com/2013/10/bye-bye-csharp-php-java-ruby-you-are-so-long-and-thanks-for-all-the-fish.html)

```
-- unpaged
with source as
(
    select distinct on (email)
         *
    from profile
    order by email desc, created_date desc
)
, paged as
(
    select *
    from source
    offset ((p_pageNumber - 1) * p_pageSize)
    limit p_pageSize
)
, all_count_and_paged_list as
(
    select
        (select json_agg(p.*) from paged p) as list,
        (select count(*) from source) as all_count
)
select row_to_json(r.*) from all_count_and_paged_list r
```

If you want to count the actual number of rows fetched by p_pageSize, get page_count:

```
, all_count_and_paged_list as
(
    select
        (select json_agg(p.*) from paged p) as list,
        (select count(p.*) from paged p) as page_count,
        (select count(*) from source) as all_count
)
```

Comment: The `ORDER BY` should be where the `LIMIT` is.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe LIMIT without ORDER works on Postgres if the source CTE / derived table is already ordered, so in spirit of avoiding code duplication, I didn't repeat the order by on paged CTE. But yeah, it's a good practice to put ORDER BY and LIMIT together, especially if the source table is not yet ordered